# How to delete all symbols that don't match the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a type that stores building numbers. If the user tries to input a wrong string it should fit the string to specified pattern. My pattern is:`[\d]+[a-zA-Z]?`, so the string should look like `103a` or `59`. And if I have something like `assdas103a4asdas1231as1` it should delete all except `103a`.

Comment: _" if I have something like assdas103a4asdas1231as1 it should delete all except 103a"_ - but `4a`, `1231a` and the final `1` also match?

Comment: If a user entered something like `assdas103a4asdas1231as1`, would it not be better to tell them to enter something that is actually valid than trying to make sense out of nonsense?

Comment: Rather than deleting the non-matching parts, simply string.join the matches. If you want only the first match, use that.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so mark one of the replies below as the answer. If it is not add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should delete all except 103a.

Then only take the first match by calling `Match` such as:

```
var str = "assdas103a4asdas1231as1";

var buildingNumber = Regex.Match(str, @"[\d]+[a-zA-Z]?").Value;
```

Result put into `buildingNumber` is:

```
103a
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by finding the first match and storing it in a capture group, then replacing its text with the captured text.

`^.*?(\d+[a-zA-Z]?).*`

- `^.*?` matches as few characters as possible from the start of the line, meaning it will stop at our first match:
- `(\d+[a-zA-Z]?)` is your existing regex, placed in a capture group.
- `.*` continues until the end of the line.

Replacing this with the contents of group 1, `\1`, we turn the captured `assdas` `103a` `4asdas1231as1` into just `103a`.

Note that the anchor (`^`) isn't required, but they improve performance on a non-matching line because the engine won't attempt the match again on every starting position.

If you like, you could also just grab the first match and use its value instead of bothering to do it with a regex substitution. In that case you would not need the surrounding `.*` expressions.

Comment: If you're giving example code it would be best if it was functional. At the very least, valid C#...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an environment to test this on and saw no other answers. I'll remove the bad example.

Comment: I liked your answer and +1 it. But I would suggest that your `.*?` be swapped out for `\D*` because the `.` will match anything and digits; so hence why not make the parsers operations more specific and less susceptible to failure by giving it a more concise rule to process. Also as an aside and along the same advice of keeping it concise for the regex parser engine; prefer to use `+` instead of `*` when you know there will be things to find. Using `*` can/does cause backtracking because the zero condition is a possibility in almost all scenarios. (It didn't apply here though). :-)

Comment: Both great points, @ΩmegaMan. I have the bad habit of using `.*` and `.*?` as shorthands instead of taking the time to think through what that character set and quantifier should be.